# Repeated object creation in php

Tags: php, ajax, object, memory-management, garbage-collection

i have my own php structure

that have controller and model now i want to export record from db to CSV file
my question is that is php can manage garbage collection or memory resources?
because every time ajax request to a controller and controller make a object of model

every request is add limited row (as i define) e.g. 1000 rows to CSV and then again a ajax request is called for the same

i have large data so i just want to know is every time creating object of controller and model are bed practice for this job?

note : i don't create constructor in both class (model)

Answer (score 0):

Every time a new request is made php creates objects, and when php has finished processing destroys them. Php does not keep anything in memory between requests, it has a "share nothing" approach. So no, you are not doing anything wrong.

If you are calling an object multiple times in your code, for example a database connection class, and you only want one instance of that object throughout that request use singletons.

```
class Singleton {

private static $instance;

   protected function __construct() 
   {
     //Do something, or don't
   }

   private function __clone() {}
   private function __wakeup() {}

   public static getInstance()
   {
       if (!static::$instance) {
           static::$instance = new Singleton();
       }
       return static::$instance;      
   }

}
```